# Replace element in GridView on element's event

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps, ads

I'm using a highly dynamic GridView inside my Windows Store App. Element's inside the GridView can have different template and size, depending on what I'm inserting inside DataSource. For instance:

```
<GridView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Featured}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MovieSelectingTemplate}"
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource FluidMovieGridItemTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource VariableSizedMovieStyleSelector}"
/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MovieSelectingTemplate">
    <TemplateSelectors:MovieTemplateSelector 
        Content="{Binding}"
        Default="{StaticResource DefaultMovieTemplate}"
        Featured="{StaticResource FeaturedMovieTemplate}"
        AD="{StaticResource ADMovieTemplate}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="FluidMovieGridItemTemplate">
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="1" ItemHeight="1"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<local:FeaturedGridMovieStyleSelector x:Key="VariableSizedMovieStyleSelector"
   NormalStyle="{StaticResource NormalMovieGridViewItemStyle}"
   ADStyle="{StaticResource ADMovieGridViewItemStyle}" 
   FeaturedStyle="{StaticResource FeaturedMovieGridViewItemStyle}"/>
```

App is about movies and as you can see we can have 3 types of templates:

- Normal movie template
- Featured movie template (2x3 normal movies size)
- AD movie template - used as scaffolding to insert adds in the grid (2x1 normal movie size)

MovieSelectingTemplate decides based on a enum in Movie class which template to use. When I need to insert ADs in a grid, I just create empty Movie with AD template. I've using Microsoft pubCenter for ads.

The problem is: pubCenter is offering a really small quantity of ads, and I would like to replace the element with AD template when the is no ad, with actual element. But I can only know that AD is not available once grid datasource was formed, so it's really hard to replace anything inside. How can I solve this?

Upd:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="ADMovieTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/logo-app-260x260.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <UI:AdControl
                                  ApplicationId="{StaticResource AppId}" 
                                  AdUnitId="{StaticResource 250x250AdUnitId}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                  Height="250" 
                                  Margin="0" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                  Width="250"
                            />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you add XAML of your `ADMovieTemplate`?

Comment: added ADMovieTemplate, @XAMeLi